# How to add values in Combox in C#.net

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one combox and i want to add value like.when user will click on combox he will see name "Dan","Peter","David" but value behind the name shoud be "1","2","3" IDs of name.How will i do this in C# windows combo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking to use the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` properties of the combobox. [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx)

Short sample:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public class Foo(int id, string name)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Then just make sure to set ID as the `ValueMember` and Name as the `DisplayMember`. Add a collection of Foo's and you're all set.

Answer (score 2):

You can add to ComboBox any class not only String. ComboBox use ToString method to show item. Please, see exalmpe:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            comboBox.Items.Add(new User(1, "Dan"));
            comboBox.Items.Add(new User(2, "Peter"));
            comboBox.Items.Add(new User(3, "David"));

            comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(ComboBoxSelectedIndexChanged);
        }

        void ComboBoxSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)sender;
            User user = (User)combo.SelectedItem;
            MessageBox.Show("User Id = " + user.Id.ToString() + ",  Name" + user.Name);   
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public long Id { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public User(long id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
}
```